# query to go back date from current date

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which there are two columns. I want to see those all rows of id or count id which have been inserted from current date to 230 days back.

For that I have used below query but it is not giving result it  shows 0 while so many rows in table

```
select count(b.id) from bill b 
 where date(b.date) between (curdate()) and (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 230 DAY))
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `date` in your table ?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: I am using date datatype to save date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the order in the beteen (smaller first)

`between (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 230 DAY)) and (curdate())`